# How to fix the error jsx no new function as prop with typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to fix the eslinting rule error jsx no new function as prop using typescript and react.

i have code like below,

```
const Parent = () => {
    const handleChange = useCallback((value: boolean) => {
         setField(value);
    }, [setField]);

    return (
        <RadioButton label="first" onChange={() => handleChange(true)}/> //error here
        <RadioButton label="second" onChange={() => handleChange(false)}/> //error here
    );
}
```

i understand that using onChange={() => handleChange(true)} is an anti pattern and hence the error . but i have tried

```
onChange={handleChange(true)} this causes maximum state update depth reached error.
```

how can i fix this such that i dont see the jsx no new function as prop error. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the callback as the prop:

```
<RadioButton label="first" onChange={handleChange}/>
```

Not 100% sure about your use case, but I'd recommend not using `useCallback`:

```
const handleChange = (value: boolean) => {
     setField(value);
};
```

Also make sure that the `RadioButton`'s `onChange` prop has the signature `(value: boolean) => void` and not using some sort of `React.ChangeEvent`. If it uses `React.ChangeEvent`, you will have to adjust the signature of `handleChange`.

Comment: thanks. but how does the value prop is passed to handleChange method now? when i call it like {handleChange} it doesnt have value within the method

Comment: What is the type definition of RadioButton's prop onChange?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const Parent = () => (
  <>
    <WrapRadioButton label='first' bool />
    <WrapRadioButton label='second' bool={false} />
  </>
)

const WrapRadioButton = (props) => {
const [field,setField] = React.useState(false)
  const handleChange = () => {
    setField(props.bool);
  };

  return (
    <RadioButton onChange={handleChange} {...props} />
  );
};

const RadioButton =(props)=>{
const myProps = props
return (<div>lalal</div>)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).